# Stacking columns with similar names in R

Tags: r

I have a CSV file whose awful format I cannot change (simplified here):

```
Inc,a_One,a_Two,a_Three,b_One,b_Two,b_Three
1,1,1.5,"5 Things",2,2.5,"10 Things"
2,5,5.5,"10 Things",6,6.5,"20 Things"
Inc,a_One,a_Two,a_Three,b_One,b_Two,b_Three
3,9,9.5,"15 Things",10,10.5,"30 Things"
```

My desired output is a new CSV containing:

```
inc,label,one,two,three
1,"a",1,1.5,"5 Things"
2,"a",5,5.5,"10 Things"
3,"a",9,9.5,"15 Things"
1,"b",2,2.5,"10 Things"
2,"b",6,6.5,"20 Things"
3,"b",10,10.5,"30 Things"
```

Basically:

- lowercase the headers
- strip off header prefixes and preserve them by adding them to a new column
- remove header repetitions in later rows
- stack each column that shares the latter part of their names (e.g. `a_One` and `b_One` values should be merged into the same column).
- During this process, preserve the `Inc` value from the original row (there may be more than one row like this in various places).

With caveats:

- I don't know the column names ahead of time (many files, many different columns).  These need to be parsed if they are to be used as logic for stripping the repetitious header rows.
- There may or may not be more than one column with properties like `Inc` that need to be preserved when everything gets stacked.  Generally, `Inc` represents any column that does not have a prefix like `a_` or `b_`.  I have a regex to strip out these prefixes already.

So far, I've accomplished this:

```
> wip_path <- 'C:/path/to/horrible.csv'
> rawwip <- read.csv(wip_path, header = FALSE, fill = FALSE)
> rawwip
   V1    V2    V3        V4    V5    V6        V7
1 Inc a_One a_Two   a_Three b_One b_Two   b_Three
2   1     1   1.5  5 Things     2   2.5 10 Things
3   2     5   5.5 10 Things     6   6.5 20 Things
4 Inc a_One a_Two   a_Three b_One b_Two   b_Three
5   3     9   9.5 15 Things    10  10.5 30 Things

> skips <- which(rawwip$V1==rawwip[1,1])
> skips
[1] 1 4

> filwip <- rawwip[-skips,]
> filwip
  V1 V2  V3        V4 V5   V6        V7
2  1  1 1.5  5 Things  2  2.5 10 Things
3  2  5 5.5 10 Things  6  6.5 20 Things
5  3  9 9.5 15 Things 10 10.5 30 Things

> rawwip[1,]
   V1    V2    V3      V4    V5    V6      V7
1 Inc a_One a_Two a_Three b_One b_Two b_Three
```

But then when I try to apply a tolower() to these strings, I get:

```
> tolower(rawwip[1,])
[1] "4" "4" "4" "4" "4" "4" "4"
```

And this is quite unexpected.

So my questions are:

1) How can I gain access to the header strings in `rawwip[1,]` so that I can reformat them with `tolower()` and other string-manipulating functions?

2) Once I've done that, what's the most effective way to stack the columns with shared names while preserving the `inc` value for each row?

Bear in mind, there will be well over a thousand repetitious columns that can be filtered down to perhaps 20 shared column names.  I will not know the position of each stackable column ahead of time.  This needs to be determined within the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the base `reshape()` function. For example with the input

```
dd<-read.csv(text='Inc,a_One,a_Two,a_Three,b_One,b_Two,b_Three
1,1,1.5,"5 Things",2,2.5,"10 Things"
2,5,5.5,"10 Things",6,6.5,"20 Things"
inc,a_one,a_two,a_three,b_one,b_two,b_three
3,9,9.5,"15 Things",10,10.5,"30 Things"')
```

you can do

```
dx <- reshape(subset(dd, Inc!="inc"), 
    varying=Map(function(x) paste(c("a","b"), x, sep="_"), c("One","Two","Three")),
    v.names=c("One","Two","Three"),
    idvar="Inc",    
    timevar="label",
    times = c("a","b"),
    direction="long")
dx
```

to get

```
    Inc label One  Two     Three
1.a   1     a   1  1.5  5 Things
2.a   2     a   5  5.5 10 Things
3.a   3     a   9  9.5 15 Things
1.b   1     b   2  2.5 10 Things
2.b   2     b   6  6.5 20 Things
3.b   3     b  10 10.5 30 Things
```

Because your input data is messy (embedded headers), this creates everything as factors. You could try to convert to proper data types with

```
dx[]<-lapply(lapply(dx, as.character), type.convert)
```

Comment: Perhaps my biggest problem with learning R is not being able to find comprehensive documentation.  For instance, within my current resources, I cannot find documentation on Map(), which you used above.  Could you provide a source of documentation for that function?  Google has not been helpful.

Comment: Within R, just type `?Map` to bring up the documentation for that function.

Comment: Awesome.  That helps if I know what I'm looking for.  Where does one go if they don't yet know what they're looking for? =)  I've been using the index [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/), but it lacks certain things I've found elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a combination of `read.mtable` from [my GitHub-only "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun) and `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package.

Here's the approach. I'm assuming your data is stored in a file called "somedata.txt" in your working directory.

The packages we need:

```
library(splitstackshape) # for merged.stack
library(SOfun)           # for read.mtable
```

First, grab a vector of the names. While we are at it, change the name structure from "a_one" to "one_a" -- it's a much more convenient format for both `merged.stack` and `reshape`.

```
theNames <- gsub("(.*)_(.*)", "\\2_\\1", 
                 tolower(scan(what = "", sep = ",", 
                              text = readLines("somefile.txt", n = 1))))
```

Second, use `read.mtable` to read the data in. We create the data chunks by identifying all the lines that start with letters. You can use a more specific regular expression if that doesn't match your actual data.

This will create a `list` of `data.frame`s, so we use `do.call(rbind, ...)` to put it together in a single `data.frame`:

```
theData <- read.mtable("somefile.txt", "^[A-Za-z]", header = FALSE, sep = ",")

theData <- setNames(do.call(rbind, theData), theNames)
```

This is what the data now look like:

```
theData
#                                               inc one_a two_a   three_a one_b two_b   three_b
# Inc,a_One,a_Two,a_Three,b_One,b_Two,b_Three.1   1     1   1.5  5 Things     2   2.5 10 Things
# Inc,a_One,a_Two,a_Three,b_One,b_Two,b_Three.2   2     5   5.5 10 Things     6   6.5 20 Things
# inc,a_one,a_two,a_three,b_one,b_two,b_three     3     9   9.5 15 Things    10  10.5 30 Things
```

From here, you can use `merged.stack` from "splitstackshape"....

```
merged.stack(theData, var.stubs = c("one", "two", "three"), sep = "_")
#    inc .time_1 one  two     three
# 1:   1       a   1  1.5  5 Things
# 2:   1       b   2  2.5 10 Things
# 3:   2       a   5  5.5 10 Things
# 4:   2       b   6  6.5 20 Things
# 5:   3       a   9  9.5 15 Things
# 6:   3       b  10 10.5 30 Things
```

... or `reshape` from base R:

```
reshape(theData, direction = "long", idvar = "inc", 
        varying = 2:ncol(theData), sep = "_")
#     inc time one  two     three
# 1.a   1    a   1  1.5  5 Things
# 2.a   2    a   5  5.5 10 Things
# 3.a   3    a   9  9.5 15 Things
# 1.b   1    b   2  2.5 10 Things
# 2.b   2    b   6  6.5 20 Things
# 3.b   3    b  10 10.5 30 Things
```